# Multiple ajax search in one page get same value on two input filed when click on value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two input filed. Where i need both of filed ajax search result. Searching result working fine. But problem is when i click on any of one search result two input filed get same value. How can i solve this problem.

*/ HTML */

```
                 <tr>
                    <td>Bus No</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="bus_no" id="bus_no" >
                        <div class="bus_no_search"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Source</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="source" id="source">
                        <div class="source_search"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

*/ javascript */

```
        // ajax search bus no

        $('document').ready(function () {
            $('#bus_no').keyup(function () {
                var bus_no = $(this).val();
                if(bus_no != ''){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax_search.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {bus_no:bus_no},
                        success: function (data){
                            $('.bus_no_search').fadeIn();
                            $('.bus_no_search').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $('.bus_no_search').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click' , 'li' , function(){
            $('#bus_no').val($(this).text());
            $('.bus_no_search').fadeOut();
        });




        // ajax search source

        $('document').ready(function () {
            $('#source').keyup(function () {
                var source = $(this).val();
                if(source != ''){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax_source_search.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {source:source},
                        success: function (data){
                            $('.source_search').fadeIn();
                            $('.source_search').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $('.source_search').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        });
        $(document).on('click' , 'li' , function(){
            $('#source').val($(this).text());
            $('.source_search').fadeOut();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: There's no issue with your existing code. I believe something else might be the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think when you click search result both li click events invoking. You should use separate selectors to them, so your click events should look like

```
//search bus no
        $(document).on('click' , '.bus_no_search li' , function(){
            $('#bus_no').val($(this).text());
            $('.bus_no_search').fadeOut();
        }); 

//search source
        $(document).on('click' , '.source_search li' , function(){
            $('#source').val($(this).text());
            $('.source_search').fadeOut();
        });
```

Comment: if it was helpful and you do not have another issue just accept the answer.